# Strange error when trying to randomize a dataset

Tags: python, pandas

I trying to shuffle data with the following code.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

from sklearn.naive_bayes import MultinomialNB
 data = pd.read_csv('dataset.txt')
 np.random.shuffle(data)
```

Running this however gives me the following error. I dont understand where this error is coming from.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "sample2.py", line 12, in <module>
 np.random.shuffle(data)
File "mtrand.pyx", line 4668, in mtrand.RandomState.shuffle (numpy/random /mtrand/mtrand.c:30498)
 File "mtrand.pyx", line 4671, in mtrand.RandomState.shuffle (numpy/random/mtrand/mtrand.c:30438)
 File "/Users/marcvanderpeet/Library/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 1992, in __getitem__
 return self._getitem_column(key)
 File "/Users/marcvanderpeet/Library/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 2004, in _getitem_column
 result = result[key]
 File "/Users/marcvanderpeet/Library/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 1992, in __getitem__
 return self._getitem_column(key)
 File "/Users/marcvanderpeet/Library/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 1999, in _getitem_column
 return self._get_item_cache(key)
 File "/Users/marcvanderpeet/Library/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py", line 1345, in _get_item_cache
 values = self._data.get(item)
 File "/Users/marcvanderpeet/Library/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/internals.py", line 3225, in get
 loc = self.items.get_loc(item)
 File "/Users/marcvanderpeet/Library/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/indexes/base.py", line 1878, in get_loc
 return self._engine.get_loc(self._maybe_cast_indexer(key))
 File "pandas/index.pyx", line 137, in pandas.index.IndexEngine.get_loc  (pandas/index.c:4027)
  File "pandas/index.pyx", line 157, in pandas.index.IndexEngine.get_loc (pandas/index.c:3891)
  File "pandas/hashtable.pyx", line 675, in pandas.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item (pandas/hashtable.c:12408)
  File "pandas/hashtable.pyx", line 683, in pandas.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item (pandas/hashtable.c:12359)
```

Any thoughts on what goes wrong here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are applying a numpy function to a pandas dataframe.

You can convert the dataframe to a numpy array and shuffle that:

```
 np.random.shuffle(data.values)
```

Or you can use a pandas function:

```
data = data.sample(len(data))
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't really understand the whole traceback but to me the error simply comes from the fact that a dataframe is not a numpy array. To fix it just use the actual underlying array of the dataframe using `data.values`.

My guess for what happends in the traceback is that `np.random.shuffle` does not check if the input is a valid array and tries to operate and grab data from the  dataframe the same way it would for a regular array hence all the error regarding `getitem` and so on.